# Java: Static transient fields

Tags: java, serialization, static, field, transient

I just found out in Java you can declare a field 'static transient' - the compiler doesn't complain. This doesn't seem to be useful in any way since static fields are not serialized, as we all know.

But I wonder, is there actually a case where 'static transient' fields are useful?

Comment: static transient fields can be detected via reflection.  You can write your own serializer to do XML, JSon, etc and you can give this a special meaning if you intend to save static variables as well.

Comment: +1 for getting a use case. My understanding was it's redundant.

Comment: BTW: You can have other modifier combinations which don't make as much sense like public constructor on an abstract class or a protected constructor/method of a final class.

Comment: With reflection any modifier combination can make sense (more or less) ;-)

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey: I suggest you repost your above response as a separate answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thing is: it is probably safe to say that it's one point where the Java specs could have been clearer.  They could have prevented *"static transient"* and hence made the point of custom serializers moot.

Answer (score 18):

Nope - you said it yourself, static fields aren't serialized.

Kinda weird that the compiler lets you do that though.

Comment: They are not serialized by the built in Java serializer. However other serializers can behave differently.

Comment: And even with another serializer, the point of saving static fields is...?

Comment: @Peter, By the way serialVersionUID would be an exception.

Comment: @UstamanSangat Or one can just drop "non-ObjectO" paradigms and be happy with standard serialization behaviors ..

Comment: Nothing 'weird' about it. It's legal syntax, with a plausible implementation. No reason why the compiler should get involved in the Java Object Serialization Specification.

Answer (score 17):

In most cases, it is not useful. Static fields are indeed not serialized by the default serializer.

However, `static` `transient` fields can be detected via reflection. If someone writes its own serializer and he wants to also serialize static fields, then he *might* take the `transient` keyword in consideration and skip the serialization of that particular field.

*PS: This answer is posted for the sake of completeness, and is based on [Peter Lawrey's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565653/java-static-transient-fields#comment5008564_4565653). Credits to him.*