# What is the effect of static final transient in Java?

Tags: java, static, final, transient

In the code base I am working on, nearly all variables that are declared `static final String` are also declared `transient`.

So I have fields like:

```
public static final transient String VERSION = "1.0";
```

I am tempted to remove these `transient` keywords whenever I spot them, because I think it doesn't serve any purpose.

Is there any difference in behaviour between using `transient` or not in this case?

Comment: I assume that you are especially referring to the combination with `final`, so that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565653/java-static-transient-fields would not be a reasonable duplicate, right?

Comment: please have a look here :) [transient variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables) – Ruthi Ruth

Comment: Who uses serialization anyway?  Remove all transients ! :)

Comment: My question is why you have these VERSION-variables. My guess is that they were hardcoded to "1.0" when the class was created, and then remained unchanged for the years after this. Remove the whole thing if you ask me.

Comment: @Tobb: VERSION was just an example. It's basically used for all String constants

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `static` field is implicitly `transient` (when serializing a `static` field, its value will be lost anyway). So indeed, no need to declare both.

Comment: Would be great if you could add a source, but it looks like it's the correct answer anyway.

Comment: When you say the value is lost, does the field be part of the serialization without a value(say null) or does the field never feature as a property ?

Answer (score 2):

The `transient` keyword on a variable will ensure that the variable is not part of the serialized object when serializing. If your class is not `serializable`, nor a JPA entity (which uses the transient keyword to avoid storing variables in the database), removing it should be fine.

Comment: Most of these classes do implement Serializable

Comment: Ok, as the other answer states, static members aren't serialized anyways. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000975/are-static-variables-serialized-in-serialization-process

Answer (score 1):

static members are associated with a class not with the object, hence on deserialization you  will see the value you passed on, as opposed to the default values shown while using transient.
To have a better understanding try to change the value of the variables after serialization and then on deserialization you will see that the values of serialized members are same but static one has changed.
As per the **transient final** ,final variables do participate in serialization directly by thier values,hence no use of declaring a final variable as transient.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't see what this adds to the accepted answer.