# JAVA - Implementing a serialisable and mutable Singleton

Tags: java, oop, serialization, singleton

I am currently developing an Object-Oriented system in java. I am required to assign a unique integer identifier for every object within the application, and to be able to serialise and deserialise the entire contents of the application. I was pointed to the Singleton design pattern as a means of storing the java equivalent of "global variables", but the common implementations in java using a Class or Enum are unserialisable or immutable respectively. How would I go about making a singleton that is both mutable and serialisable?

Below is my current java code for a Singleton class I have written which should be non-serialisable since idCountSingleton is static:

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class idCountSingleton implements Serializable{

    private static idCountSingleton INSTANCE;
    private int count;

    private idCountSingleton(int id){

        idCountSingleton INSTANCE = new idCountSingleton(id);
        count = id + 1;

    }

    public int getID(){
        return this.count;
    }

    public idCountSingleton getInstance(){
        return this.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile. Please post your actual code.

Comment: I don't think your code does what you want. You declare a local variable named `INSTANCE` and assign to that, so your static `INSTANCE` field is always `null`. The `count` field is never changed. Is that what you want?

Comment: @tgdavies The intention is that **count** gets incremented whenever **getInstance()** is called. Clearly I have not been able to implement that.

Comment: 1. This is not a singleton. It isn't anything in particular, just a piece of non-working code. 2. Nobody can call `getInstance()` since you need an instance to call it on, and you can only get one from `getInstance()`, which should therefore be `static`, in which case it won't compile because of `this`, which also needs changing. 3. It *is* serializable. 4. The `count` variable must always be 1 for a real singleton, so it is therefore pointless. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part is to get `INSTANCE` assigned correctly on deserialisation.

If you deserialise and then simply call `getInstance` you'll get a fresh instance of your singleton and lose the value of id.

You can set INSTANCE by adding a side-effect to `readObject` which sets the static field:

```
package com.example.so;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serial;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializableSingleton implements Serializable {
    private static SerializableSingleton INSTANCE;

    private long id;

    public static synchronized SerializableSingleton getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            System.out.println("Creating new SerializableSingleton");
            INSTANCE = new SerializableSingleton();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    long getAndIncrementId() {
        return id++;
    }

    @Serial
    private synchronized void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        s.defaultReadObject();
        INSTANCE = this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        if (new File("test").exists()) {
            try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test"))) {
                // read and discard the object
                ois.readObject();
                System.out.println("Read singleton, next id:" + SerializableSingleton.getInstance().getAndIncrementId());
            }
        }
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test"))) {
            oos.writeObject(SerializableSingleton.getInstance());
        }

    }
}
```

I have changed your class to increment the id when you get an id from an instance, instead of when `getInstance` is called, so that you can't accidentally get the same id twice.

Answer (score 0):

A singleton does not have to be immutable: all that the singleton pattern asserts is that there only exists one of this object type within the whole application. Other objects that want to access an `idCountSingleton` can only retrieve it using the `getInstance()` method, and cannot create it themselves.

To finish making the class singleton:

1. Ensure the `getInstance()` method is also static, so that other classes can access it by the class name (like `idCountSingleton.getInstance()`)
2. I'd highly recommend following this pattern within the `getInstance()` method:

```java
public static synchronized idCountSingleton getInstance() {
    if(INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new ClassSingleton();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

The if-null check lazily constructs the object, waiting for `getInstance()` to be called before creating the singleton object. The `synchronized` keyword in the method signature ensures that only one thread at a time can enter the method to additionally handle race conditions (e.g., what happens if two threads make it past the if-null check before either creates the object?)

Serializing the object (presumably, on shutdown/autosave) can then be handled by accessing the object with `getInstance()` from whatever class saves the application state, and deserialization can happen within the private constructor (assuming that this is a singleton object, you can save its data to a fixed location)

To note: the only thing you need to serialize is the `count` field. `static` fields are functionally [transient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565653/java-static-transient-fields).